# Python Program not working properly

Tags: python

```py
from math import factorial as f
a=int(input("From "))
b=int(input("To "))
x=float(input("??? "))
if a<b:
    for k in range(a,b+1):
        x+=(2**(k+1))*f(k)*f(k)/f(2*k+1)
        if k%1000==0:print("reached",k)
    print(x)
else: print("Wrong values, a must be smaller than b")
```

After running the program in terminal for input a=0, b=1000 and x=0, the program gave "2.0" as output.
But when I ran it on the Jupyter notebook, the output was "3.1415926535897922".

How can I fix it?

[image: Image from my computer]

Comment: I have tried again, but get "2" even now, I have added a image to my post.

Comment: @karel The code runs fine in python2 and python3. If you look at the screenshot, you will see that the syntax error was a typo that the OP fixed and re-ran the code successfully the second time. The different values are because [python3 supports true division while python2 uses integer division](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39106941/1081936), so this is 100% a programming question about the differences between python2 and python3.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code that you are tried to run gave different results in Python 2 in the terminal and Python 3 in Jupyter notebook because of the different ways that Python 2 and Python 3 handle floating point numbers (integer division vs. true division in Python 3).

In Python 3 the results of the code are as follows.

```
From 0
To 1000
??? 0
reached 0
reached 1000
3.1415926535897922
```

In Python 2 the results are the same except for the last line which is 2.0.

A better way to run this code block from the terminal is to install the *python3-ipython* package that allows you to copy/paste the whole code block into the terminal and to run it similar to the way that a block of Python code runs from a cell in Jupyter notebook when you press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

To install python3-ipython open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install python3-ipython
```

To start the ipython3 interpreter type `ipython3` and to exit from the ipython3 interpreter type `exit`